# uiwebview crash when alert after popped

Tags: ios, uiwebview, crash, alert

`UIWebView` crashes when I pop the custom webViewController while the javaScript code calls the `alert()` function and the alert viewController shows, then if I click the "ok" button of the alert view, the app will crash. I think that is because the alert view's delegate which is actually `UIWebView` has been released.

Does anybody have a workaround for this problem?

Comment: can you show the crash report

Comment: UIKit -[UIWebView webView:runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:]
CoreFoundation ___invoking___
CoreFoundation -[NSInvocation invoke]
CoreFoundation -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]
WebKitLegacy -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:]
SEGV_ACCERR

Comment: this crash log is caused by call comfirm(), that is the same as calling alert().   Or may be it is because the javascript context has been release, the alert and confrim function of uiwebview is actually complicated.